# ODP.Net 11.2.0.2.0 doesn't support 64 bit Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Tags: c#, exception, oracle11g, odp.net, odp.net-unmanaged

I am using ODP.Net 11.2.0.1.0 with Oracle product version 11.2 and Oracle.DataAccess.dll 32-bit as it is compatible with ODP.NET 11.2.0.1.0.

As my entire application is built on 32 bit, sometimes we observe out of memory exceptions.

For resolving memory out of exceptions, I am upgrading my application to 64 bit. But 64 bit Oracle.DataAcess.dll is not compatible with current version of ODP.Net 11.2.0.1.0

Is there any way I can fix this issue without upgrading the ODP version.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use the managed driver?

Comment: My project is bit old one. Based on that time ODP.Net 11.2.0.1.0 was latest version.Managed drivers are available from ODP.Net 12+ right?

Comment: Then why not use it? The api is almost identical so it shouldn't be an issue to upgrade and you can say goodbye to 32/64b issues.

Comment: It is common one for many application So it would be bit difficult to upgrade the version. Is there any other way

Comment: Then I don't see any easy options, unless your memory issues are memory leak issues that can be fixed.

Comment: okay.. If I need to upgrade ODP.Net, Is that required to upgrade entire oracle software?

Comment: No, if you move to ODP.net, you actually no longer need an Oracle client which makes deployment a lot easier.

Comment: Your problem is that you need x64 client to match x64 version of that DLL. If you want to use managed and client-less data access, all you will need to do in your app is replace DLL reference and change namespace from `DataAccess` to `ManagedDataAccess`. Api is the same 99%. There are small differences, you are not likely going to encounter. This question is well answered on SO otherwise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle.DataAccess.Dll loading issue on x-64 machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213678/oracle-dataaccess-dll-loading-issue-on-x-64-machine)